# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have downloaded and installed Crystal Report for Visual Studio 2012, but I didn't found crystal report viewer in my tool box items. I searched in tools->Choose toolbox items but didn't find it.

I have this exception in my web site

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine,    Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies.      The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Also I downloaded DLL crystal report from this link, and I made addReference [http://www.dlldll.com/crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.dll_download.html] but also same exception.

can anyone help me

Comment: You need to create it as a new project, so take a look in your reporting projects, or are you trying to being it into a WinForms, WPF or ASP.Net app?

Comment: i have a web site application(asp.net and C#) containing crystal reports , i opened this app in visual studio

Comment: In the toolbox, do you see the reporting set of tools?

Comment: thx i changed the assembly version in web config to make it same of assembly in my computer         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>